# Merging DataFrame row values into string by level

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following DataFrame...

```
           code
player_id      
223336        4
223336        5
223336        4
225987        2
225987        3
225987        4
```

How can I merge the "code" column into a string so the result would look like...

```
             code
player_id      
223336        454
225987        234
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your data source? Text file or databases?

Comment: Just these 6 values, or a general solution?  IE will you always be doing it with three value chunks?

Comment: This is just a slice of the DataFrame... so a general solution.

Comment: @zoosuck: It's a pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 5):

You could

- convert the code column values to strings (using `astype`),
- then use `groupby` to group those values according to the index, and finally
- aggregate the groups using `''.join`

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
df = df.set_index('player_id')
strjoin = ''.join
print(df['code'].astype(str).groupby(df.index).agg(strjoin))
```

yields

```
player_id
223336       454
225987       234
Name: code, dtype: object
```

---

Another option is to

- `groupby` the index,
- then aggregate the groups using `join_digits`, which multiplies the values by
  powers of 10 then sums the result.
- use `astype(str)` to convert the ints to strings

---

```
def join_digits(series):
    return (series * 10**np.arange(len(series)-1, -1, -1)).sum()

df['code'].groupby(df.index).agg(join_digits).astype(str)
```

yields

```
player_id
223336       454
225987       234
Name: code, dtype: int64
```

Note, however, that calculating using integers will give a different result than the first method if the ints in `df['code']` are not single-digit numbers. And moreover, if the left-most digit is a zero, the zeros will be dropped.

Comment: If there's ever been a pythonic answer to a question, it's this.